# yet another map/set iterator not incrementable, but this time it's C++11

Tags: list, visual-studio-2012, c++11, dictionary, iterator

Here's my precious little piece of code that makes my VC++ 2012 shiver, whereas if I run the same code on a Mac, there seems to be no problem at all.

```
for(auto trace : _traces) {
    std::list<tuio::Cursor> cursors = trace.second.cursors;

    std::vector<Vec2f> v;
    for(tuio::Cursor p : cursors) {
        v.push_back(p.getPos());
    }
    if(v.size() > 2) {
        BSpline2f l(v, min((int)v.size()-1, 3), false, true);
        PolyLine2f pl;
        for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
            float t = (float)i/(float)v.size();
            pl.push_back((l.getPosition(t)*s)+o);
        }
        gl::draw(pl);
    }


    tuio::Cursor c = cursors.back();
    gl::drawSolidCircle((c.getPos()*s)+o , _scale * 10.0f);
}
```

at this point it would make sense to let you know that `_traces` is a `std::map<int, TouchTrace>` and `TouchTrace` is a class I defined, which is basically a container for a list of `tuio::Cursor` plus some additional awesomeness. I figure it matters quite little for this questions, especially since the members are public and I directly deal with them, so you can effectively see all my dirty laundry here in this snippet.

The trouble is that I randomly get a "map/set iterator not incrementable" exception, especially when I go a bit crazy and draw a very long trace (but fecal matter happens sometimes for shorter traces, that's the problem with random things). Plus, it only happens when I lift my finger off the tabletop (you get the idea) at which I perform this nifty little piece of code here:

```
void TheApp::cursorRemoved(tuio::Cursor cursor) {
    _traces[cursor.getSessionId()].addCursorUp(cursor);
    _traces.erase(cursor.getSessionId());
    // Well, that was abrupt.
}
```

Note the comment, in case you need to smack me with a hard stick if the problem turns out to be some weird kind of cross-run between this main thread and the drawing thread. At this point it would probably matter, or not, to let you know I'm using libCinder, although I know very little about its internals so I can only speculate that the application and the drawing run in different threads. Anyways.

The backtrace identifies that `for` on the first line, and of course the exception is thrown by `std::_Tree_const_iterator<something>`, about which I suspect I should know nothing, Jon Snow. The `auto` thingie seems to work properly, or at least that's what VS tells me, so I figured something was wrong with the `foreach` construct and rewrote it with explicit iterators and the like.

How wrong I was. Next, I changed the auto into their explicit types, but nothing got better. Well, not really, since at some point I got a different exception, something about list iterators not being compatible, which is why I threw the autos away and hard-coded the actual types.

Although at this point I'm effectively employing plain old C++03 techniques, the rest of the code is still being compiled as C++11 by VS 2012, which is not exactly known to be reliable when dealing with cutting edge technology (as a matter of fact, the last time I checked, which is just more than six months ago, it didn't even support range-based for loops).

Any idea appreciated.

Comment: there's no such thing as precious code, and you need to compile your code before running it ;), so you're probably not formulating your question precicely, but mere ranting. You might be using an iterator from a temporary object. Have you debugged? Which line is crashing?

Comment: Who said I didn't compile it? I effectively lose thirty seconds of my life every time I hit F5! :) Hence I'm not ranting either. I assure you that if I was ranting, you wouldn't have seen a single line of code ;) Now, as to the serious part of your comment, that's remotely likely, but as far as I could verify, I'm not. I'm making copies of everything, as far as I can be sure of this (which is not very much, but still).

Comment: surely, running it without compiling would be quite hard :). What about the loop (see my answer below). You're probably modifying your map while iterating through it

Comment: If you more than one thread is accessing `_traces` at the same time, and at least one of them calls a non-const method (notably `operator[]` is non-const on `std::map`) that's a data race: undefined behavior. You're going to have a bad time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you erase a cursor from `_traces` while being in the loop `for(auto trace : _traces) {`, the loop iterator gets invalidated

Comment: Yes, that's entirely possible. As a matter of fact, I commented out the erase from that second snippet and I managed to not get a crash for quite a while. A feasible approach would probably be to have an isVisible member in the TouchTrace, set it to false to prevent it from being drawn (pending modifications to the drawing code), and having it erased after a short delay.

Comment: here's a question about something similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17230779/iterating-through-stl-containers-and-removing-adding-multiple-items