# Iterating through STL containers and removing/adding multiple items

Tags: c++, c++11

One of the most frequent errors that occur in my code is that STL containers are modified during a loop.

Elements are removed or added during a loop execution so I usually run into out of bounds exceptions.

My for loops usually looks like this:

```
for (auto& Item : Items) { // Will not work when Items container is modified
    //... loop logic
}
```

When multiple items can be removed, I use this monstrosity:

```
for (int Index=Items.size()-1;Index<=0;Index--) {
    if (Index<Items.size()) { //Because multiple items can be removed in a single loop
        //... loop logic
    }
}
```

This looks bad and it makes me feel bad using that second option. The reason multiple items can be removed is due to events, where a single event can remove any number of elements.

Here is some pseudo code to illustrate when this occurs:

```
// for each button in vector<button> {
// process button events
// event adds more buttons to vector<button>
// *ERROR* vector<button> is modified during loop.
// }
```

In another example, imagine a vector with following items:

```
// 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

We start our loop at `0` and go element by element. At `4`, I want to remove elements `1`,`4` and `9` so we can't use a normal loop here.

Comment: You can simply modify the iterator when removing or adding elements - as long as you know, how many items are modified and where.

Comment: @Spook I usually don't know what and where, an event can remove any number of elements at any time during a for loop.

Comment: Well, if you really don't know when and where elements might be removed (and how many), your only option is to make a copy of the container and modify that... Otherwise there's no way to get this working.

Comment: This begs a question though, if pressing button 4 removes button 9, and you actually remove it, and then pressing button 5 should remove button 9... it is the same "9" or does it remove what was formerly the 10th element ? In other words, are your elements identified by a key or by their position in the container ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `std::remove_if` with a predicate that decide if a button needs to be removed:

```
bool needsRemoved(const Button& button);

vec.erase(std::remove_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), &needsRemoved), vec.end());
```

**EDIT**: For your last example, the quadratic (i.e. bad for performance) algorithm is:

```
std::vector<int> vec = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
auto end = vec.end();
for (auto it = vec.begin(); it < end; ++it)
{
    std::set<int> bad = {1, 4, 9};
    end = std::remove_if
        (vec.begin(), end,
         [bad](int x) { return (bad.find(x) != bad.end()); });
}
vec.erase(end, vec.end());
```

You will probably be better off using a container with fast lookup though (like a set, or a map).

Comment: How does this solve his problem.  His problem is that something in button 4 might remove buttons 1, 4 and 9.  Invalidating the iterator in his loop.

Comment: @James Kanze, I omitted the last part, see edited answer, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @rectummelancolique I still doubt that your solution can be made to work.  If the "buttons" are GUI components, they are probably not copyable, and they are probably polymorphic.  In which case, the actual elements in the container are pointers, which means that `remove_if` cannot be used.

Comment: @James Kanze, I'm only reusing the exemple the OP provides. In any case, I don't see why you couldn't use `remove_if`. If they are not copyable then they cannot reasonnably be put in a `vector` in the first place. If they are pointers, in the above, Iterating from `end` to `vec.end()` to delete the objects before calling erase is simple enough. Not to mention the use of smart pointers instead of regular ones.

Comment: @rectummelancolique I realize that.  But if the example doesn't make sense with regards to the text?  (And the example clearly doesn't explain everything.)  WRT pointers: there's too much we don't know to answer (Formally, deleting a pointer from a container before it has been removed from the container is undefined behavior.  But it will work in practice, _unless_ other code tries to use it.)

Comment: @James Kanze I believe it to be very well defined. After you delete a pointer element, the pointer is invalid, and if you dereference it then yes, you obviously risk a total protonic reversal, just like with a pointer not in a container. But I'm no standard guru, so if you have chapter & verse about this, I'll be happy to read it and ceoncede your point. When you say *unless other code tries to use it* what are you referring to?

Comment: @rectummelancolique The standard requires that the elements in
a container be copyable, and even requires them to be copied in
specific cases.  A pointer to deleted memory is not copyable.
(It has been rendered "invalid", see §3.7.4.2/4.)  In practice,
the container will not copy it unless required to, and there are
very few, if any implementations still existing where copying it
will not just copy the bits, with no problem.  But §3.7.4.2
still makes it undefined behavior.

Comment: @rectummelancolique The "unless other code tries to use it" is simply referring to the fact that his function is obviously accessing other elements in the list (since it may delete them).  His whole problem stems from the fact that an action on item 4 may delete item 1, 4 and 9.  I don't quite see how `remove_if` can be made to work in this case.

Comment: Ah a well hidden footnote in the draft I got hold of explains why. Thanks! There are some crazy systems out there :) Point conceded my good sir. Still, I maintain a smart pointer solves the issue.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32175/discussion-between-rectummelancolique-and-james-kanze)

Answer (score 3):

There are pretty much two ways to do this reliably:

1. Iterate over a copy of the original container and manipulate the original. This may not be feasible unless your container stores pointers, not the actual elements directly.
2. Don't allow direct manipulation of the container, but instead mark the to-be-deleted elements somehow and sweep them after iterating. You can also support adding new elements by inserting them into a separate temporary container and appending to the original after the loop is done - you can also do this with the removed elements, obviating the need to store a "removed" flag in the elements themselves. This can of course be abstracted out with suitable `add` and `remove` functions.

**Edit:** The removal part of solution #2 can be nicely done with the erase-remove idiom shown by rectummelancolique.

Comment: The second solution is the canonical solution, but I'm not sure it applies here (or at least, it requires a bit of extra work).  In his example, processing button 4 may remove button 9, so he shouldn't process button 9 later in the loop.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Well, you could skip those elements that are marked while iterating. I'm not sure, however, that in his use case it actually is a good idea to do that - it creates an asymmetry where, for example, processing element 2 causes the removal of elements 1 and 3, only #3 can be skipped as #1 was already processed.

Comment: @JohannesD I don't know.  In fact, supposing that the buttons are buttons in a GUI interface, I have my doubts about the approach of iterating over the buttons in general.  In most cases, you will want to process the events in the order they arrive: you should queue the events, using a classical FIFO queue.

Comment: @JohannesD Re your edit: if the "buttons" in question are GUI components, they probably aren't copyable and probably are polymorphic.  In which case, the objects in the container are pointers, and you can't use `remove_if` on the container.

Answer (score 0):

Since there are buttons (and I hope there are not too many) you might want to add a flag to each button, which tells, if it has been processed completely or something like that. Then you look for the first item in the array which has not been processed and process it. You repeat this until all items have been processed.

```
for (;;) // breaks, when all items have been processed.
{
    auto it = std::find( std::begin(Items), std::end(Items), 
        [](const Item & item){ return item.hasBeenProcessed(); }
    if ( it == std::end(Items) )
        break;
    process( *it );
}
```

This should be safe. Note that this can have quadratic time complexity with respect to the number of items. As I said, there will hopefully not be too many items. If this is an issue, you might want to optimize this loop a little, for example starting the search where you left the last time. But do this only when it becomes an issue.

Comment: This is more or less what I suggest as well (although I'd write it cleanly, without a break).  I don't think quadratic time is an issue, if the objects really are buttons; how many buttons can a human user press in the time it takes to process them?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're talking about buttons and button events: the
simplest solution is simply to reset the loop to the start when
you process an event:

```
for ( auto current = items.begin(); current != items.end(); ++ current ) {
    if ( current->hasEventWhichNeedsProcessing() ) {
        current->processEvent();    //  possibly invalidates current
        current = items.begin();    //  revalidates current
    }
}
```

*If* we're talking about button events (which occur due to
a human user action), this should be safe,  since you should
normally be able to process all of the events before a new event
occurs.  (For very rapidly occuring events, you may never reach
the final entry.)

I'm still not sure that it's the best solution, however.
Regardless of how you iterator, it means that you may treat
events in a different order than they arrive.  A better solution
would be to push the events themselves onto a list, and then
process this list in order (as a queue).